# MSMQ Clustering

Tags: msmq

Is MSMQ Clustering only available in the Enterprise Edition of windows Server ?

Answer (score 2):

I think so, if by "Clustering" you mean Failover Clustering, which is only available on the Enterprise and higher grades of Windows Server

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Windows Clustering is an Enterprise only (and higher) feature of Windows.